# Using Auto Layout to position a self-resizing view

Tags: cocoa, ios7, uikit, autolayout

I have a custom view that implements `sizeThatFits:` and occasionally resizes itself (it adjusts its height based on its width). I want to position this view ("A") above its sibling ("B") using Auto Layout so I have a constraint that sets the bottom of A equal to the top of B.

While A's frame does grow and shrink, B's frame does not move with it. What is the recommended way to implement a self-resizing view that can be used with Auto Layout?

Answer (score 2):

You must not set A's size manually; that defeats auto layout (and auto layout will override it when layout occurs). You must implement this view's `intrinsicContentSize` and use that to dictate the size of the view. Now when the time comes to resize A, call its `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`. This will cause layout to be performed. `intrinsicContentSize` will be called, and constraints will operate (because layout is being performed in good order).

One more thing: it sounds like you may be underdetermining the constraints here. You must not just position A above B; you must say, in addition to its size, where its top and left go (or its center, horizontally and/or vertically). In other words, once you are doing auto layout you must do it all the way. Otherwise things will not happen as you expect.

Comment: The height of my custom view is determined by its width (it is laying out text) but `intrinsicContentSize` doesn't give me a rect like `sizeToFit:` does. I'm thinking to expose a property called `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` like UILabel does.

If all goes to plan, I'll get a view that determines its own height and the code that uses the view can use constraints to specify its width and position.

Comment: Listen to what I said. If you want to use auto layout you cannot position this view using a rect and setting its frame. No. You must use constraints to position its x and y. This leaves only the size (height and width) and `intrinsicContentSize` will give you those. If width is fixed, then give it a width constraint too (or a trailing constraint), and return `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric` for the width in the size you return from `intrinsicContentSize`.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. I'm planning on using constraints to specify the position of my custom view, but my custom view needs to know its width in order to calculate its height in `intrinsicContentSize`. The Apple docs say "This intrinsic size must be independent of the content frame" so I thought I'd borrow UILabel's approach of exposing a `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property as a way to get a width for the purpose of calculating the height.